# C# Read from Data (CSV) & Search

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, dictionary, lookup

I have a question with regards to getting data from CSV or is there any other format recommended? And what array or dictionary or lookup I should be using?

In my WPF object I plan to have a search box, and a list box that shows the results of the search.

The database is made up of two columns eg.

> Shelly, Good
>   Joe, Happy
>   Albert, Clever
>   Shelly, Pretty
>   Jessica, Lovely
>   Joe, Great

So first column is the name of someone and the second column is the adjective for it. I am just making an example to illustrate. Basically I will search on the first column, and it is possible that a single name have "n" numbers of adjectives or even just 1.

Can I use dictionary data format? But if that is the case, can I add on to the key "Shelly" if there is another value I encounter while going through the lines?

Or is it better to use Lookup?

The size of the CSV file probably will be around 30000 rows, 2 columns. When I search Shelly I expect to get Good, Pretty which I can use to fill up my listbox.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use everything you wrote here. Good luck.

Comment: Probably shouldn't use a dictionary, as won't be able to add Shelly twice, unless you do `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: Why not create a little class with the name and list of adjectives? It would be a *LOT* cleaner that a nested collection of base types that no-one can guess what they do without actually reading the code that produces them

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. So from what I can see, it's better to use dictionary and not lookup? I was thinking lookup might be simpler if it can store similar keys but keys with different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *wouldn't* use nested collections for this. Are you sure you will remember what all these strings do next week? How about the doule indexing required to get at one of the adjectives, eg `dict["Lucy"][1]` ?

Create a small class that contains the name and the adjectives for that name and bind to a list of its instances. Creating the list from a CSV is no harder (actually *easier*) than creating the nested structure. You can use the name as the key to a dictionary to make lookups easier.

You can use the [GroupBy overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts both a key and content selector to separate the name from the adjectives.

For example :

```
class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string[] Adjectives{get;set;}
}

Dictionary<string,Persons> _persons;

var lucysAdjectives = _persons["Lucy"].Adjectives;
```

To create the list, you group the CSV values as you would to create the dictionary. Assuming your CSV parser returns a sequence of Item1, Item2 objects, you could write :

```
_persons = csvRows.GroupBy(
                            pair=>pair.Item1, //The key to group by
                            pair=>pair.Item2  //The group's contents
                      )
                     .ToDictionary(
                            g=>g.Key,
                            new Person{
                                        Name=g.Key,
                                        Adjectives=g.ToArray()
                            }
                      );
```

Assuming the file doesn't contain headers, quotes etc, you could just read each line and split it. In this case, you could read a file into the `_persons` dictionary like this:

```
_persons = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
               .Select( line  => line.Split(','))
               .GroupBy( pair => pair[0], 
                         pair => pair[1])
               .ToDictionary( g => g.Key,
                              new Person{ Name=g.Key, Adjectives=g.ToArray()});
```

You can simplify the code by adding a constructor to Person that accepts a name and a `IEnumerable<string>` and/or make it immutable to prevent accidental modifications eg :

```
class Person
{
    public string Name{get;}
    public string[] Adjectives{get;}

    Person(string Name,IEnumerable<string> adjectives)
    {
        Name=name;
        Adjectives=adjectives.ToArray();
    }
}


_persons = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
               .Select( line  => line.Split(','))
               .GroupBy( pair => pair[0], 
                         pair => pair[1])
               .ToDictionary( g => g.Key,
                              new Person(g.Key, g));
```

or create the Person objects from the group, then create a dictionary from the Persons

```
_persons = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
               .Select( line  => line.Split(','))
               .GroupBy( pair => pair[0], 
                         pair => pair[1])
               .Select( g => new Person(g.Key, g)) 
               .ToDictionary( person => person.Name,
                              person => person);
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to create the small class (why?) and the dictionary's scope is small, eg a single method, you could use C# 7's tuples.

```
var persons = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
               .Select( line  => line.Split(','))
               .GroupBy( pair => pair[0], 
                         pair => pair[1])
               .Select( g => (Name=g.Key, Adjectives=g.ToArray())) 
               .ToDictionary( person => person.Name,
                              person => person);
```

The scope has to be small because tuple names are just compiler magic. The fields are actually named Item1, Item2 etc. Compiler magic allows you to refer to them by name.

You can't define tuple types or aliases either, which means that you have to repeat the tuple definition in return types, field declarations etc :

```
Dictionary<string,(string Name,string[] Adjectives)> _persons ;
```

The code gets ugly very quickly

Comment: Thanks for answer. There is a lot of information probably I can't understand too much of it since I am still quite new to this. So when the csv is being read line by line how does the group by actually deals with duplicated names, does it search for the same key and add to the adjectives?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my project is targetted for .Net framework 3.5 so I cannot use the ReadLine method. I will try with streamreader and see how it goes, parse line by line and insert them into the dictionary line by line. I am not sure if it is possible to use the group by method.

Comment: Use ReadAllLines in .NET 3.5. It returns an array of all lines so the code doesn't have to change. As for duplicates , you didn't mention any duplicates, nor does your sample contain any duplicates. If you want to remove duplicate adjectives use [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct(v=vs.110).aspx), eg `Adjectives=g.Distinct().ToArray()`

Comment: Finally, the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. One of the reasons you should upgrade yesterday is that TLS 1.2 support was added in 4.5. Nowadays almost all services require HTTPS with TLS 1.1 at least. Many require TLS 1.2. You may not be able to even *connect* to any service like Google, AWS or Azure if you remain on 3.5

Comment: Yup, I would love to upgrade but I am not sure whether it will work. Because I am making a small tool as a WPF class library and perhaps the software that it will be used on does not support the new .NET version.

As for duplicates sorry for the confusion, what I meant was for example in the sample, "Shelly" is duplicated twice, so if I were to add into the dictionary line by line, perhaps there will be an error due to duplicated key? (which is Shelly in this case) Maybe group by will handle the duplicates?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string[]> databaseData = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();  

                databaseData = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                    .GroupBy(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1])
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());`

Would this be good I wonder? I am still trying to learn more about how select, groupby and todictionary works :D

Comment: Why use nested collections? They make the code harder to read. I've done this in the past. You *won't* remember what's in which collection, or how many levels deep in one week, much less one month. Is this string a name or adjective? Who's adjective?

Comment: If you insist on using native types, check [System.Collections.Generic.MultiValueDictionary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/)  whose code can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Generic.MultiValueDictionary/System/Collections/Generic/MultiValueDictionary.cs). You can specify a HashSet as the inner collection to eliminate duplicates

Comment: Thanks. I will try and check it out. So far it seems to be returning results correctly. Yup indeed it is better to make the code easier to read. I will brush it up soon as I will now do some debugging.
Very interesting indeed how the group by works. Feels like it is sorting, and removing the duplicate keys?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Dictionnary <string, List<string>>` to store the values.

As in your case the name seems to be the key and may have multiple values.

When you parse the CSV you need to check if the dictionnary contain the Key "Shelly" if not you create the entry <"Shelly, new list{"the adjective you actually got">

if the key "Shelly" exists, you just add your current adjective to the value list.

Comment: Will it be computationally expensive to always recheck the whole dictionary if the key "Shelly" exists? I am just afraid of the long computation time to parse through 30000 keys for instance.

Comment: To read datas from the CSV to the dictionnary i would use an intermediary class to store EACH row f the csv as <name: "shelly", Adj:"Pretty">

Then with a good LINQ query groupBy Name you could generate the dictionnary quite easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
IDictionary<string, IList<string>> myData = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
```

Key value holds Shelly, and List will hold {Good, Pretty}

Comment: Thanks! I learn a bit more about the IDictionary vs Dictionary after searching around a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below to store values

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> databaseData = new  Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

and to search use below:

```
List<string> results; 
databaseData.TryGetValue("Shelly", out results);
```

Replace `Shelly` with your search variable. For the above example results will hold Good, Pretty.

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't use `Where(x=>x.Key ...)` with a dictionary. Might as well use a `List<string,List<string>>` if you do that. Use `TryGetValue` to *quickly* get at the inner list.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated, yeah that is much simpler

Comment: Thanks I will probably use that method then to search for results once I get a good way to read from CSV to the dictionary.